# Different font on strong elements for Internet Explorer 11 and Safari on iOS 9

Tags: html, css, ios, internet-explorer, fonts

I have a web app with two fonts, Amatic SC for `h1` and `h2` and Open Sans for the rest. The webpage displays `strong` text fine on most browsers:

[image: Display on Firefox and most browsers]

For Safari on iOS 9 (tested on iPhone 4S) and Internet Explorer 11 on Windows 8.1 (tested on LambdaTest), the `strong` elements use the font from the `h1` and `h2` elements:

[image: Display on iOS 9 Safari and Internet Explorer 11]

The relevant CSS for these elements is:

```
@font-face {
  font-family: 'Amatic SC';
  font-style: normal;
  font-weight: 400;
  src: url(/fonts/amatic-sc-v13-latin-regular.woff2) format('woff2'), url(/fonts/amatic-sc-v13-latin-regular.woff) format('woff'); }

@font-face {
  font-family: 'Amatic SC';
  font-style: bold;
  font-weight: 700;
  src: url(/fonts/amatic-sc-v13-latin-700.woff2) format('woff2'), url(/fonts/amatic-sc-v13-latin-700.woff) format('woff'); }

@font-face {
  font-family: 'Open Sans';
  font-style: normal;
  font-weight: 400;
  src: url(/fonts/open-sans-v17-latin-regular.woff2) format('woff2'), url(/fonts/open-sans-v17-latin-regular.woff) format('woff');
}

@font-face {
  font-family: 'Open Sans';
  font-style: bold;
  font-weight: 700;
  src: url(/fonts/open-sans-v17-latin-700.woff2) format('woff2'), url(/fonts/amatic-sc-v13-latin-regular.woff) format('woff');
}

body {
  font-family: 'Open Sans', sans-serif;
}

h1, h2 {
  margin: 0.5rem 0 0.5rem 0;
  text-align: left;
  font-family: Amatic SC, cursive;
  font-weight: bold;
}
```

The website is at [www.emotionathletes.org](http://www.emotionathletes.org) if you want to further inspect.

What is the reason for the use of a different font on iOS Safari and Internet Explorer?

### Minimal reproducible example

Following the comment, I narrowed the issue to the loading of the fonts. If I load them in the `head` of the HTML, linked to Google Fonts, then the page displays well. If I load them locally in the CSS with `@font-face` from a `woff` or `woff2` file, then the strong elements display with a different font on iOS 9 on iPhone 4S and on Internet Explorer 11 on Windows 8.1. The order of loading the fonts in the CSS does not change the result.

A minimal reproducible example has HTML file `strong.html`:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html><head>
    <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8"><meta charset="utf-8"><meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, maximum-scale=1.0, minimum-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="strong.css">
    <link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.gstatic.com"> 
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Open+Sans&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Amatic+SC&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
  </head>
  <body>
    <h2>Summary</h2>
    <p>The Bulgy series, whose first season is "Emotion Athletes", has the following purposes:</p>
    <ul>
      <li>
        transform the <strong>difficulties</strong> of the <strong>pandemic</strong> into   <strong>opportunities</strong> for children to <strong>recognise what they are feeling,   understand the reason, and use their emotions</strong>;
      </li>
    </ul>
  </body>
</html>
```

and CSS file `strong.css`:

```
/*
Amatic SC and Open Sans are Google Fonts:

https://fonts.google.com/specimen/Amatic+SC?sidebar.open=true&selection.family=Open+Sans#about

https://fonts.google.com/specimen/Open+Sans?sidebar.open=true&selection.family=Open+Sans#about

*/


/* comment these @font-faces for the page to work properly. */

@font-face {
  font-family: 'Amatic SC';
  font-style: normal;
  font-weight: 400;
  src: url(/fonts/amatic-sc-v13-latin-regular.woff2) format('woff2'), url(/fonts/amatic-sc-v13-latin-regular.woff) format('woff'); }

@font-face {
  font-family: 'Amatic SC';
  font-style: bold;
  font-weight: 700;
  src: url(/fonts/amatic-sc-v13-latin-700.woff2) format('woff2'), url(/fonts/amatic-sc-v13-latin-700.woff) format('woff'); }

@font-face {
  font-family: 'Open Sans';
  font-style: normal;
  font-weight: 400;
  src: url(/fonts/open-sans-v17-latin-regular.woff2) format('woff2'), url(/fonts/open-sans-v17-latin-regular.woff) format('woff');
}

@font-face {
  font-family: 'Open Sans';
  font-style: bold;
  font-weight: 700;
  src: url(/fonts/open-sans-v17-latin-700.woff2) format('woff2'), url(/fonts/amatic-sc-v13-latin-regular.woff) format('woff');
}


body {
  font-family: 'Open Sans', sans-serif;
}
  
h1, h2 {
  font-family: 'Amatic SC', cursive;
}
```

I put a live version at [www.emotionathletes.org/strong.html](https://www.emotionathletes.org/strong.html), with CSS file at [www.emotionathletes.org/strong.css](https://www.emotionathletes.org/strong.css).

For my own reasons, I prefer to serve the font files from my server than query them from Google Fonts. How can I serve the font files locally and still display them properly on Safari and Internet Explorer?

Comment: It seems that the Open Sans font impact the `<strong>` style in IE: https://i.stack.imgur.com/kIPaj.gif. I also compare the styles in IE and Chrome, I found that the `font-weight` inherit `400` in IE, but it is `bold` in Chrome: https://i.stack.imgur.com/rDESG.png. I think the `font-weight: 400` overrides `font-weight: bold` and the Open Sans font which lead the issue in IE. But when I download the source file of the website to debug, it displays well in IE. It could be better if you can provide **a minimal code snippet** which can reproduce the issue.

Comment: @YuZhou Thanks for the investigation. This is curious indeed. I updated the question with a minimal reproducible example in the text and also online.

Comment: @YuZhou Thanks for your help in debugging this. The issue was simply a typo in the url to the WOFF font file. I have now fixed it and am happy to close, delete or move this question, since it's not about programming.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue was in the code, which I found today as I was changing the main font:

For `Open Sans` at `700`, the `woff` filepath was:

```
/fonts/amatic-sc-v13-latin-regular.woff
```

and should have been:

```
/fonts/open-sans-v17-latin-700.woff
```

Older browsers use `woff` and not `woff2`, and so they were doing exactly as they were told. I now fixed the issue.

Moral of the story: if using local fonts for performance, make sure to do the right wiring of CSS to filepaths.